# Where clause with function causing "is not a valid query expression"

Tags: ecto, elixir

I have this working query:

```
  products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
  join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
  join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
  join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
  join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
  where: c.id in ^categories,
  where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
  select: [p, c, s]
```

I just want to add in one more `where` clause, to account for `keywords`. EG if the user entered some keywords, only return products if the keywords are in either the product name or product brand.

My attempt:

```
def are_keywords_in_product(keywords, product) do
  IO.inspect(product)
  Enum.map(keywords, fn(keyword) -> 
    product.name =~ keyword || product.brand =~ keyword
  end)
end

def create_query(keywords, categories, shop_ids) do
  products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
  join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
  join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
  join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
  join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
  where: c.id in ^categories,
  where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
  where: are_keywords_in_product(keywords, p), 
  select: [p, c, s]
end

def create_query(nil, categories, shop_ids) do
  products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
  join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
  join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
  join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
  join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
  where: c.id in ^categories,
  where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
  select: [p, c, s]
end

    ......create_query(keywords, categories, shop_ids) |> Api.Repo.all
```

Effectively my last `where` clause in `create_query(keywords)` should return true if the keywords are in the product name or brand (I might need to try and return false instead of nothing, if keywords not found in product?).

I'm getting this error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/api/router.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `are_keywords_in_product(keywords, p)` is not a valid query expression.

* If you intended to call a database function, please check the documentation
  for Ecto.Query to see the supported database expressions

* If you intended to call an Elixir function or introduce a value,
  you need to explicitly interpolate it with ^

    expanding macro: Ecto.Query.where/3
    lib/api/router.ex:169: Api.Router.create_query/3
    expanding macro: Ecto.Query.select/3
    lib/api/router.ex:169: Api.Router.create_query/3
    expanding macro: Ecto.Query.from/2
    lib/api/router.ex:169: Api.Router.create_query/3
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: I think you need to do ^(are_keywords_in_product(keywords, p))

Comment: @jonzlin95 It says `undefined function p/0`. So it seems like the `p` argument is not being evaluated as the product. I tried `^(are_keywords_in_product(keywords, ^p))` too, and it said `cannot use ^p outside of match clauses`

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see what are_keywords_in_product is doing now, and I'm unsure if Ecto supports that out of the box. I think your best bet is to write yourself a [fragment](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) for the function instead.

Below code is just a starting point. Didn't actually write out the correct SQL query.

Something along the lines of

```
def are_keywords_in_product(keywords) do
  Enum.map(keywords, fn(keyword) -> 
    "(?) =~" <> keyword <> " || (?) =~ " keyword
  end) |> Enum.join("")
end
```

and in the query

```
where: fragment(^(are_keyswords_in_product(keywords)), variables)
```